Does Microsoft Teams tooling allow administrators to see users with LinkedIn accounts that are looking for a job?
If I link my work Microsoft Team's account to my LinkedIn profile, can my organization's Microsoft 365 administrators see information that indicates I'm looking for a new job?
I'm concerned about that information being exposed to the organization.
Does LinkedIn protect me from that risk?

Question's off-topic here but might be on-topic on https://serverfault.com. You may need to narrow the scope. Resources for you: Integrate LinkedIn in Microsoft Entra ID LinkedIn account connections data sharing and consent Risk and compliance solutions > Content search in Microsoft Teams

@Blindspots why would the question be off-topic here? We even have a tag for [tag:office-365] how is asking a question about whether or not it gives admins a perm/capability off topic?

This is a question about tools available to admins of third-party IT platforms which appears on-topic for them. See What questions can I ask here. Multiple sites have ms365 /office365tags. Your question is specifically about administration IT platform. If you want to know how to link your profile then that would be a good fit. Further, for any site there should be a specific problem to solve that is reasonably scoped. You should also consider [security.se]

@Blindspots asked on meta, https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5264/1066

I’m voting to close this question because it isn't reasonably scoped to the functions of a specific web app, or a problem you are experiencing. Question is being discussed on Meta

Voted to reopen as it's about webapps. The MS Teams admin center is https://admin.teams.microsoft.com and the MS 365 admin center is
https://aka.ms/admincenter
